# Event count at certain time interval in riemann

Tags: clojure, riemann

I have to check the number of count appearing in an event at each interval of every 30 seconds. If the count is greater than 5 means, I need to trigger an email.

I am using the below code, but email didn't get triggered.

```
(let [userindex1 (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))]
  (streams
    prn
    userindex1))

(streams
  (where (and (service "system_log")
              (not (expired? event)))

    ; fixed-time-window sends a vector of events out every 30 seconds
    (fixed-time-window
      30
      ; smap passes those events into a function
      (smap
        (fn [events]
          ;Calculate the no of count of events for failure
          (let [numberofFailure (count (filter #(="IE" (:description %)) events))]

            {:status "login failures"
             :metric  numberofFailure 
             :totalFail (boolean(numberofFailure > 5))}

            (streams
              prn
              numberofFailure))))


      ;check if the variable status is true if condition satisfied then trigger an email
      (let [email (mailer {:host "smtp.gmail.com"
                           :port 25
                           :user "aaaaa"
                           :pass "bbbbb"
                           :auth "true"
                           :subject (fn [events]
                                      (clojure.string/join ", "
                                                           (map :service events)))
                           :from "abc@gmail.com"})]
        (streams
          (where (and (:status "login failures")
                      (:totalFail true))
            (email "123@gmail.com")))))))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There are quite a few missing pieces on this snippet but regardless of that there are some obvious wrong expressions as `(and(:status "login failures") (:totalFail true))` (it will always produce nil). I suggest you to test line by line at the REPL and use a different thread to periodically check the counter value wrapped into an [atom](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. I'll try to address some of them, then post a minimal working example:

1. The first fn passed to [smap](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-smap) should return an event. That event can be created with `event` or by `assoc`'ing into one of the received events. In your sample a plain map is created (which would not work, it's not a proper event), but that's even lost because then `streams` is called (which AFAIK should only be called at the top level). So instead of:

   ```
   (smap
     (fn [events]
       (let [numberofFailure ...]
         {:status "login failures"
          :metric  numberofFailure 
          :totalFail (boolean ...)}
         (streams
           prn
           numberofFailure)))
     ...)
   ```

   You should do something like:

   ```
   (smap
     (fn [events]
       (let [numberofFailure ...]
         (event {:status "login failures"
                 :metric  numberofFailure 
                 :totalFail (boolean ...)}))
     ...)
   ```
2. To calculate `totalFail` remember that you need to use prefix notation to call `>`, so it must be `(> totalFail 5)`. And `boolean` is not needed, as `>` will already return a boolean.
3. I would initialize the mailer out of the top-level `streams` call, as an enclosing scope using `let` or with a `def`. But it should work as it is.
4. You should pass the last `where` as a children stream to smap, so it must be the second argument to smap. Let's recall the [smap docs](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-smap):

   ```
   (smap f & children)
   Streaming map. Calls children with (f event), whenever (f event) is non-nil.
   Prefer this to (adjust f) and (combine f). Example:

   (smap :metric prn) ; prints the metric of each event.
   (smap #(assoc % :state "ok") index) ; Indexes each event with state "ok"
   ```
5. The last `where` should not be enclosed by `streams`, and the `and` sentence must work on the `event`, so it must be:

   ```
   (where (and (= (:status event) "login failures")
               (:total-fail event))
     (email "123@gmail.com"))
   ```
6. The `:subject` fn for `mailer` should be passed as part of a second map, as explained in the [`mailer` documentation](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.email.html#var-mailer)
7. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/aphyr/riemann/issues/563) on `fixed-time-window` which makes it a bit unreliable: it doesn't fire as soon as the time window is due but waits until a new event is fired, so you might want to use a different windowing strategy until that get's fixed.

Here goes a full minimal working example based on yours:

```
(let [email (mailer {:host "localhost"
                     :port 1025
                     :from "abc@gmail.com"})]
  (streams
    (where (and (service "system_log")
                (not (expired? event)))
      (fixed-time-window
        5
        (smap
          (fn [events]
            (let [count-of-failures (count (filter #(= "IE" (:description %)) events))]
              (event
                {:status "login failures"
                 :metric  count-of-failures 
                 :total-fail (>= count-of-failures 2)})))
          (where (and (= (:status event) "login failures")
                      (:total-fail event))
            (email "hello123@gmail.com")))))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much nberger. Your explanation was awesome which clearly taught me the functionality of the code. But still the email didn't get triggered as you said there was a bug in fixed-time-window. I removed the  fixed-time-window.Still the last where condition in my code was not working.

Comment: Eventhough I removed the and condition from my code but still I am facing the same issue. I am posting my latest code for your review.

Comment: (let [email (mailer {...})]
  (streams
    (where (and (service "system_log")
                (not (expired? event)))
      
        (smap
          (fn [events]
            (let [count-of-failures (count (filter #(= "IE" (:description %)) events))]
              (events
                {:status "login failures"
                 :metric  count-of-failures 
                 :total-fail (> count-of-failures 5)})))
          (where (= (:status event) "login failures")
            (email "123@gmail.com"))))))

Comment: Its working when I removed this line (not (expired? event))) form the (streams... I couldn't find out the logic happening here.

Comment: Maybe it's just that there are not enough events during the time window. To simplify things, you could use `rate` and `scale` to accomplish what you are doing with the `fixed-time-window` and `smap`. [See this gist](https://gist.github.com/nberger/fc636d8c2712b38a39f5) for a new version using `rate` and `scale`. If you are not sure if there are enough events, I left a couple `prn` so you can see if the rate is not enough, or if there's an issue with the mailer configuration.

Comment: If it's not clear what `scale` and `rate` do, [this answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/riemann-users/3yWmtAehqoA/7yDBebw5iYIJ) by @aphyr might be of help. There's also the [docs about rate](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-rate).

Comment: I used rate and scale but it didn't works for me. May be I am using it in wrong way.

Comment: The above edited code is working by using fixed-time-window itseld but it triggering email for N number of condition satisfied with in 30 sec(for eg.If my condition was true for 10 times within that 30 sec means 10 emails got triggered). I want only one email at the end of every 30sec if the condition is satisfied. If no event matches my condition within 30sec interval means no email should trigger.